# How to find a record having all required has_many associations in join table instead of OR / IN query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I have a Restaurant Table, a Cuisine Table, and a join table connecting the Many To Many.  I want to find a Restaurant that matches two specific cuisines, i.e., find the Restaurant that is listed in the join table with connections to Cuisine 1 and Cuisine 2.

I could hack something together with each and includes, but it feels like there must be some direct and obvious thing I'm missing in building my query using ActiveRecord.

```
Restaurant
ID| Name
1 | McDonalds
2 | Taco Bell

Cuisine
ID| Style
1 | American
2 | Mexican 
3 | Fast Food 

Restaurant_Cuisines
ID | Restaurant_ID | Cuisine_ID
1  | 1             | 1
2  | 1             | 3
3  | 2             | 2
4  | 2             | 3
```

I want to be able to query for restaurants that serve both American & Fast Food, which would give me back McDonalds but not Taco Bell as Taco Bell serves Fast Food but not American.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following query which may not be most optimised solution but it gives correct answer and can guide in a direction to get optimised answer.

```
rest_ids = Restaurant_Cuisines.where(Cuisine_ID: 1).pluck(:Restaurant_ID) && Restaurant_Cuisines.where(Cuisine_ID: 3).pluck(:Restaurant_ID)
Restaurant.where(id: rest_ids)
```

If needs to be generalized:

```
def specific_restaurant(cuisine_ids)
  ids = cuisine_ids.map { |id| Restaurant_ID.where(Cuisine_ID: id).pluck(:Restaurant_ID) }.reduce(:&)
  Restaurant.where(id: ids) if ids.present?
end
```

Definitely `N+1` where `N` is `cuisine_ids` but no harm if `N` is limited/few.

**UPDATE - Finally, single query!**

```
def specific_restaurant(cuisine_ids)
  ids = RestaurantCuisine.where(cuisine_id: cuisine_ids).group(:restaurant_id).having("count(*) = #{cuisine_ids.count}").pluck(:restaurant_id)
  Restaurant.where(id: ids) if ids.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the IDs of the foreign keys, you can use a `joins` and pass the ids of the join table like this:

```
cuisine_ids = Cuisine.where(Style: ['American', 'Mexican']).pluck(:id)

restaurants = Restaurant.joins(:cuisines).where(cuisines: {id: cuisine_ids})
```

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but if cuisine_ids were [1,2], wouldn't this return all Restaurants where cuisine is 1 OR 2?  I need AND.

Comment: @thumbtackthief yes it would return based on an OR condition. It would be worth while posting the database you are using as well since the functions required are likely to be database specific

Comment: @engineersmnky It's a SQLITE database using ActiveRecord.  I'll post a sample

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes but your answer was both incorrect _and_ condescending, which is quite the special combination.

Comment: @thumbtackthief at the time of my original answer, there was no information about the OP's schema. I've updated my answer and removed comment which might be mistaken as "condescending".